# ajax cross domain not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

**Error :**

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:8080, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

```
$("#selector3").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {               

                $.ajax({
                   url: "http://example.com/"+$("#selector3").val(),
                    type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: request,
                        processData: true,
                        data: {},

                        headers: { 
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "origin, content-type, accept"
                                    },

                        crossDomain: true,
                    success: function(data) {   
                        alert(data.Company_Id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for cross domain scripting.

**Check below sample code:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/" + $("#selector3").val(),
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp', // Notice! JSONP <-- P (lowercase)
    data: request,
    processData: true,
    data: {},
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "origin, content-type, accept"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.Company_Id);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have changed datatype : jsonp, I get response error in                             ( Error: jQuery1113042518210380525434_1461646502000 was not called )

Comment: @Arunkumar, That means either a network error or an end point that doesn't return a JSONP response.

Comment: Not a real solution if you set a bearer token or any header parameter, `headers` is totally ignored

Answer (score 0):

The headers you send to the server from Javascript, should be returned by the server. If you have no access to the server this will be impossible. This means the server accepts your domain as a legal processor.

Next to that you can try a JSONP call. Check this URL: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Answer (score -1):

you can't do ajax operaitons on other websites source code except you have rights. you have to to that on the server side. in php you can use cURL, in .net you can use html agility pack.