# access-control-allow-origin error when executing ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I get the `Cross origin request denied` error.

Here's what I tried

```
 var data_send = JSON.stringify({
  "email_to": "mati.cazas99@gmail.com",
  "name_to": "mati",
  "subject": "hola"
});

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://webhook.site/36abc701-73f2-41bb-9db5-2a38c40c5c29",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": data_send
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I have tried everything, but I can't solve it.

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: have you enabled the CORS setting for webhook.site?

Comment: Ok. This option " Add CORS Headers ". have to checked it?

Comment: yes, i also tried that and still trows the same error

Comment: hmm. i tried your code. there seems to be no error.

Comment: Look at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834549/ajax-cross-domain-not-working-in-jquery

Comment: i tried your code in a JSBin and it works well

https://jsbin.com/banecopehe/edit?html,output

Maybe its a browser related issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow this from Backend.

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, there seems to be no CORS error here.

This is what i tried

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<Html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script>

    var data_send = JSON.stringify({
  "email_to": "mati.cazas99@gmail.com",
  "name_to": "mati",
  "subject": "hola"
});

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://webhook.site/36abc701-73f2-41bb-9db5-2a38c40c5c29",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": data_send
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
    </script>
    </body>
</Html>
```

[image]

Its just that response is being empty? is that the issue